# If I approach Earth in a near-light-speed spaceship, assuming I'm unaware, I'd think Earth is nearing me at light speed. Where is time slower?

Tags: special-relativity

If I am traveling in a spaceship with uniform motion near the speed of light towards a stationary observer on Earth, assuming I am not aware of the situation, then I would assume that Earth is approaching me at approximately the speed of light. Where is time passing slower now?

According to the theory of relativity, both the observer and I would believe that time is passing more slowly for the other. How can both be true? Nobody would be wrong with that Assumption. It is a fact that time is passing slower for both of us in a way.

Comment: Where is time passing slower for whom?

Comment: You have come upon what is known as "The Twin Paradox" where we attempt to discover which twin is younger after such a trip.    There is a ton of stuff written about this, including many many videos.  I strongly suggest that you watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRuVGOm7560 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGoAZKyI6ZY that will both explain the real problems with the various explanations you will see.

Comment: Different observers have different notions of time. both observers measure their time to move faster than the other. There is no contradiction.

Comment: Every clock runs faster in its own frame than in any other.

Answer (score 2):

The light from earth will be blue shifted and  everything you see on earth will appear speeded up by the same factor. The people will run faster, cars will travel faster etc.

The earthlings looking up at you will also see the light from you blue shifted by the same factor, and so they will see you move faster than if you were at rest.

If you were moving *away* from earth everything would appear to  be moving *slower*  for both you and the earthlings.

Where is the  paradox with this?

Comment: The OP asks "where does time run slower?"  The wording is suboptimal but it seems clear to me that this is not a question about doppler shifts, but rather a question about the speeds of clocks in various frames.

Comment: @WillO  "time" (or clocks) do not "run slower" in moving frames.  Clocks observed from *different* frames *appear* to run slow or fast, and that is exactly what  the Doppler shift is.  The twin "paradox" is a different matter.

Comment: Again, the  original question is too poorly worded for either of us to be sure what's meant, but the OP never mentions appearances.  And of course every clock certainly does run slower in some frames than it does in others.